# In 1 Chronicles 4:39, where is Gedor located?

Tags: 1-chronicles, judah

> <sup>**39**</sup> And they went to the entrance of Gedor, even unto the east side of the valley, to seek pasture for their flocks. <sup>**40**</sup> And they found fat pasture and good, and the land was wide, and quiet, and peaceable; for they of Ham had dwelt there of old.
>
> <sup>**41**</sup> And these written by name came in the days of Hezekiah king of Judah, and smote their tents, and the habitations that were found there, and destroyed them utterly unto this day, and dwelt in their rooms: because there was pasture there for their flocks. (1 Chronicles 4:39-41)

Question: Where is Gedor located? In Hebrew, it seems to indicate that it is a town in the mountains of Judah, named along with Halhul and Beth-zur (Joshua 15:58). However, other commentaries seem to disagree and place it in Arabia and in other places. Does anyone know where Gedor is?

Answer (score 1):

First - the Hebrew word in question in 1 Chron 4:39 is גְדֹ֔ר = "Gedor".

The LXX has Γέραρα = "Gerara".

The Cambridge commentary has this:

> 39. the entrance of Gedor] R.V. the entering in of Gedor. The Gedor of Joshua 15:58 is identified with Jedur, Ijdur (north of Hebron,
>     Bädeker, p. 135), the neighbourhood of which seems an unlikely scene
>     in the days of Hezekiah for the exploit described in 1 Chronicles
>     4:41. LXX. has Gerar (cp. Genesis 20:1; Genesis 26:1), perhaps
>     rightly.

The Pulpit commentary has this:

> Verse 39. - The place Gedor cannot be identified in this connection.
> There is a town of the name situated in the mountainous district of
> Judah between Halhul and Beth-zur, to the north of Hebron (Joshua
> 15:58). It is evident that this cannot be the place we require here.
> There is another town of the name (1 Chronicles 12:7), probably
> belonging to Benjamin, and which as little admits of being fitted in
> here. Both the Alexandrine and the Vatican Codex of the Septuagint,
> however, evidently read גְּדרָ for גְּדֹר. Now, Gerar of the
> Philistines would suit well for position and description, and also
> (Genesis 10:14) for the allusion found here (ver. 40) to the dwelling
> there "of old" of the people of Ham. The Hebrew word, however,
> generally applied to the valley of Gerar (נַחַל, wady) is not the word
> used here of Gedor (הַגָיְא, ravine). See Stanley's 'Syria and
> Palestine,' p. 159, and note. Not only are references frequent to the
> fertility of Gerar, but the significance of that in 2 Chronicles 14:14
> speaks for itself. This alteration of reading, however, with
> acceptance of the Septuagint manuscripts, cannot be regarded as
> altogether satisfactory, and Keil ('Comm.,' in loc.) offers some
> suggestions of weight against those of Ewald, Bertheau, and others. 1
> Chronicles 4:39